# Disable past dates from default HTML date picker in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, date, picker, disable

I would like to disable past dates (and times) on my default HTML picker. I didn't create it with any framework, it's just the default one that goes like this:

```
<label for="time">Date & Time</label>
            <input
            type="datetime-local"
            id="time"
            name="time"
            required>
```

I have tried this code below for input **[type="datetime-local"]** that I found but no success yet. All I can find when researching about this is in regards to date pickers in jQuery or disabling date pickers that come from a library/framework.

```
function datePicker() {
    const formElements1 = form1.querySelectorAll("input, select");
    form1.querySelector("#time").min = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]; 
}
```

Comment: Try leaving the time in the string. `new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 19);`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Great, that works, thanks:) But now the issue is that I'm getting the seconds with it too which I don't want. It should be hour + minute only.

Comment: Just change the `19` to `16` to leave out the seconds.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Makes sense now, thanks for your help!